# Multiplication in Python Lists

Tags: python-3.x

I want to multiply my list by 10.

```
V=[45,33,65,90]
```

I have tried:

```
V1= 10
V=[45,33,65,90]
print(V1 * V)
```

Expected answer

```
[450,330,650,900]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [237]: V=[45,33,65,90]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [238]: V1 = 10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [239]: [n*V1 for n in V]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[239]: [450, 330, 650, 900]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map method.

```
V=[45,33,65,90]
V1= 10

V = list(map(lambda x:x*V1, V))

print(V)

#‘Output = [450,330,650,900]’
```